# Automate Export of Data from Rally

Tags: automation, rally

Has anyone done automation of extract/exporting data from Rally. Right now I log into rally and export data manually. I want to be able to automate it.
Can you please help me by pointing out to the right links or maybe provide me with some sample code.
I want to learn so more the info the better.

Regards,

Subro

Answer (score 2):

This repo contains code that will export attachments... perhaps it could be used as a starting/learning point:

> https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-Export-Attachments